# Javascript countdown stop

Tags: javascript, countdownjs.js

I am using this countdown plugin for online examination.

https://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/

[image]

It works fine but i am not sure how can i stop the countdown. Only the on Complete trigger option availble.

Please anyone help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: This plugin don't support a stop of the countdown. You can either choose another one or rewrite the code. I recommend the first solution.